# Getting a "too many values to unpack" value error

Tags: python

**I've looked at other answers but it looks like they use 2 different values.**

The code:

```
user = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
info = [['a','b','c',], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]

for u, g in user, range(len(user)):
    print '|',u,'|',info[g][0],'|',info[g][1],'|',info[g][2],'| \n'
```

So basically, it needs to output:

```
'| X | a | b | c |'
'| Y | d | e | f |'
'| z | g | h | i |'
```

But instead, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    for u, g in user, range(len(user)):
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

As far as I know both user and range(len(user)) are of equal value.

Comment: Aside: If you really do want a list and its indexes, try: `for g,u in enumerate(user):`. But, as others have said, in this case you **don't** want indexes, you want `zip`.

Answer (score 14):

```
for u,g  in user, range(len(user)):
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
for u,g  in (user, range(len(user))):
```

i.e a tuple. It first returns the `user` list and then `range`. As the number of items present in `user` are `3` and on LHS you've just two variable (`u`,`b`), so you're going to get that error.

```
>>> u,g = user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-162-022ea4a14c62>", line 1, in <module>
    u,g = user
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

You're looking for `zip` here(and use string formatting instead of manual concatenation):

```
>>> user = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> info = [['a','b','c',], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
for u, g in zip(user, info):
    print "| {} | {} |".format(u," | ".join(g))
...     
| X | a | b | c |
| Y | d | e | f |
| Z | g | h | i |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for u in user:
    print '|',u,'|',info[user.index(u)][0],'|',info[user.index(u)][1],'|',info[user.index(u)][2],'| \n'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> g = 0
>>> for u in user:
...     print '|',u,'|',info[g][0],'|',info[g][1],'|',info[g][2],'| \n'
...     g=g+1
... 
| X | a | b | c | 

| Y | d | e | f | 

| Z | g | h | i |
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works too:

```
>>> for i in zip(user,info):

    print i[0],'|',

    for x in i[1]:

        print x,'|',

    print
```

And I get the output:

```
X | a | b | c |
Y | d | e | f |
Z | g | h | i |
```

P.S.:I know there have been a couple of answers, But I just thought this is also a way to get the result and thats why I have added it!